# numpy.ndarray object is not callable when trying to change x-Ticks

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am currently working on a university project where I want to plot sentiment scores over a period of time. I've attached a picture of said scatterplot. I now want to change the xticks, the xtick labels and the title. However, when trying to change the x-ticks to the quintils of the dates, i get the error "'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

[image: My current Scatterplot]

I want the xticks to reflext the min, max, 25%, 50% and 75% quntils of the dates. Since the dates are formatted as yyyymmdd, just calculating the quintils wont work but  at this point I have really lost focus on how to solve the problem. Same goes for the changing of the title, though that seems more straight forward.

My code is:

```
import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import scipy.stats as stats

# Korrelation überprpfen

correlation, p_value = stats.pearsonr(df_tagesspiegel_final['Datum'], df_tagesspiegel_final['compound'])

print(correlation)

print(p_value)

# Scatterplot erstellen

sns.scatterplot(x='Datum', y = 'compound', data=df_tagesspiegel_final)

#Quintile als xticks speichern

xticks = [df_tagesspiegel_final['Datum'].min(), df_tagesspiegel_final['Datum'].quantile(0.25), df_tagesspiegel_final['Datum'].quantile(0.5), df_tagesspiegel_final['Datum'].quantile(0.75), df_tagesspiegel_final['Datum'].max()]

plt.xticks(ticks=xticks)

plt.set_title('Korrelation von Datum und compound')

plt.set_xlabel('Datum')

plt.set_ylabel('compound')

fig.show()
```

~~~

I tried updating matplotlib, changing `plt.xticks(ticks=xticks)` to `plt.xticks(ticks=None)`. Nothing worked. I only get the error: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.

I expect the xticks to change in any way really, though I am sure that calculating the quintils of dates is not the right way to go about it.

EDIT: I've found the solution for the title problem: I used .set_title instead of title.

Comment: which line of code is raising the error?

Comment: @Learningisamess plt.xticks(ticks=xticks)

Comment: [\[SO\]: Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
**[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**
for more asking related details. 
Also, [\[JonSkeet.CodeBlog\]: WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) might be a good point to start.

Comment: Unable to repro. Also it's `plt.xlabel` and `plt.ylabel`, not `set_xlabel` and `set_yabel`, which are methods of an `Axes`.

Comment: @BigBen thanks a lot, I mustve checked in the wrong chapter in the docu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```py
plt.xticks(ticks=xticks)

plt.set_title('Korrelation von Datum und compound')

plt.set_xlabel('Datum')

plt.set_ylabel('compound')
```

by

```py
plt.gca().set(xticks=xticks, xlabel='Datum', ylabel='compound', title='Korrelation von Datum und compound')
```

Comment: That changed the labels and the ticks so thank you very much. I'll have to find a better way to display the date values though, since the quintils of dates dont seem to make a lot of sense.